# No muestra objeto JSON PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Deseo mostrar el resultado de la consulta en un JSON pero me da un resultado vacio,sospecho que es por SCOPE DE PHH,pero no he podido solucionarlo.

```
<?php
include('datos_bd.php');

$conectar = mysqli_connect($nombre_host, $nombre_usuario, $contrasena_usuario, $nombre_bd);

if ($conectar) {
$consulta ="SELECT * FROM casas";
if ($resultado=$conectar->query($consulta)) {
    while ($fila=$resultado->fetch_row()) {
        $id=$fila[0];
        $nombre=$fila[1];
        $codigo=$fila[2];
        $precio=$fila[3];
        $descripcion=$fila[4];
        $datos[]=array('id'=>$id,'nombre'=>$nombre,'codigo'=>$codigo,'precio'=>$precio,'descripcion'=>$descripcion);
        $datos_json = json_encode($datos);
    }
    echo $datos_json;
 }
}
```

Comment: Probé tu código, si regresa un json, probablemente tu consulta es la que no está regresando nada.

Comment: Si el echo lo pongo dentro del While si muestra los datos pero repetidos,pero si saco la variable que contiene el JSON fuera del While se muestra como vacia,que podria ser ?

Comment: Intenta dejando esta linea de código fuera del while: `$datos_json = json_encode($datos);`

Comment: Lo he solucionado utilizando :  mysqli_set_charset($conectar, "utf8");